# How to loop and display array of objects and their nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

I need help, I got stuck on objects with multiple nested arrays. I have a json file which consists of object, that holds array of objects, and these objects have another array of objects in them. What is the best way to loop through it?

```
fetch("data.json").then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += `<h1>${data.name}</h1>`;
for (i = 0; i < data.topics.length; i++) {
    
  document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += `
    <div>
    <h2>${data.topics[i].title}</h2>
    <ul id="programs">
    <li>programs title here</li>
    <li>programs title here</li>
    <li>programs title here</li>
    <ul>
    </div>
    `;
}});
```

json data looks like this:

{
"name": "Open Day Event",
"date": "July 7",
"topics": [
{
"title": "Engineering",
"id": 1,
"description": "some text here",
"programs": [
{
"title": "Some title",
"id": 1,
"description": "Some description",
"price": 30
},
{
"title": "Some title",
"id": 2,
"description": "Some description",
"price": 30
},
{
"title": "Some title",
"id": 3,
"description": "Some description",
"price": 30
}
]
},
{
"title": "History",
"id": 2,
"description": "some text here",
"programs": [
{
"title": "Some title",
"id": 1,
"description": "Some description",
"price": 30
},
{
"title": "Some title",
"id": 2,
"description": "Some description",
"price": 30
},
{
"title": "Some title",
"id": 3,
"description": "Some description",
"price": 30
}
]
},
{
"title": "English",
"id": 3,
"description": "some text here",
"programs": [
{
"title": "Some title",
"id": 1,
"description": "Some description",
"price": 30
},
{
"title": "Some title",
"id": 2,
"description": "Some description",
"price": 30
},
{
"title": "Some title",
"id": 3,
"description": "Some description",
"price": 30
}
]
}
]
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```
let html = "";


data.topics.forEach(topic => {
    html += `<h2>${topic.title}</h2> <ul>`;
  
  topic.programs.forEach(program => {
    html += `<li>${program.title}</li>`
  });
  
  html += `</ul>`
})

document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that recursively and by iterating the nested array.

Demo **:**

```js
const jsonObj = {
  "name": "Open Day Event",
  "date": "July 7",
  "topics": [{
    "title": "Engineering",
    "id": 1,
    "description": "some text here",
    "programs": [{
      "title": "Some title",
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Some description",
      "price": 30
    }, {
      "title": "Some title",
      "id": 2,
      "description": "Some description",
      "price": 30
    }, {
      "title": "Some title",
      "id": 3,
      "description": "Some description",
      "price": 30
    }]
  }, {
    "title": "History",
    "id": 2,
    "description": "some text here",
    "programs": [{
      "title": "Some title",
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Some description",
      "price": 30
    }, {
      "title": "Some title",
      "id": 2,
      "description": "Some description",
      "price": 30
    }, {
      "title": "Some title",
      "id": 3,
      "description": "Some description",
      "price": 30
    }]
  }, {
    "title": "English",
    "id": 3,
    "description": "some text here",
    "programs": [{
      "title": "Some title",
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Some description",
      "price": 30
    }, {
      "title": "Some title",
      "id": 2,
      "description": "Some description",
      "price": 30
    }, {
      "title": "Some title",
      "id": 3,
      "description": "Some description",
      "price": 30
    }]
  }]
};

function createList(parent, array) {
    array.forEach(function (o) {
        var li = document.createElement("li"),
            ul;

        li.textContent = o.title;
        parent.appendChild(li);
        if (o.programs) {
            ul = document.createElement("ul");
            li.appendChild(ul);
            createList(ul, o.programs);
        }
    });
}

createList(document.querySelector("ul"), jsonObj.topics);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```